# Access files in Swift Package

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift-package-manager

I am creating a Swift Package with some tests.

From the tests, I need to access to a file located in a directory called "Resources".

How can I do it? I am trying to access to it with `Bundle.main.path` like I would do it in a normal Xcode project (adding the file to the test target). But it doesn't work, neither I can set the target to the files.

[image]

Comment: Use `Bundle(for: type(of: self))` instead?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it doesn't work.